# Replace each occurance of forward slash in ruby string

Tags: ruby

I have a string that has the following structure:

`/base/6/value/6/start`

I want to escape each forward slash with a backward slash, to receive the following:

`\/base\/6\/value\/6\/start`

I expected this to work with `string.gsub('/', '\/)`, but that adds double backslashes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is an unterminated string literal in your code. Once you fix that, it should work fine. It should only add single backslashes. At least, it does for me. Can you post the *exact* output you are getting?

Comment: -3 points for misinterpreting a string.. nothing like some SO love on a Monday morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong?

Misinterpreting what you see. There are no "double backslashes" in the string. That's how single backslashes are displayed (in IRB and other places that use `#inspect` for displaying things)

Try this instead (puts will not additionally escape backslashes or other chars)

```
 puts string.gsub('/', '\/')
```